# Solve $a_{n} = a_{n-1} - c_{n-2} a_{n-2}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there a way to write a solution of the recurrence relation:

$$a_{n} = a_{n-1} - c_{n-2} a_{n-2}$$

with the initial conditions $a_0=1$ and some fixed positive value for $a_1$. Here the $c_n$ are positive numbers.

Comment: Is $c_n$ depends on $n$?

Comment: @Howardli621 Yes. I'd know how to solve it if $c_n$ did not depend on $n$ ;)

Comment: Don't see any reason for this to be solvable unless you specify what exactly is $c_n$.